# Moderator elections bug

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, election, serverfault

I'm getting a banner telling me to cast my last vote on the moderator elections but I've already cast three votes.  I've refreshed the page but still get the message.  I've also verified that my 1st, 2nd and 3rd choices are selected on the voting page.

Anyone else having this issue?

Comment: Getting the same, myself. 3 votes cast (and all 3 show in the candidate list) but I still see the reminder.

Comment: Thanks all, just a misinterpretation of the wording on my part.

Comment: Weirdly enough, after I vote in national elections I keep seeing these "Vote for candidate X" posters all over the place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you mean the message that says **Cast your final vote in the Server Fault 2011 community moderator election!** then *I believe* that's just a system message reminding people to vote. I agree the wording could be clearer though.

[image]

Comment: Yup, that's the one.  Maybe you're right and it's just bad wording.  Thanks +1

Comment: +1 What's pointed out here is a System Message and displays for everyone regardless of having voted, or even if they're allowed to vote.

Comment: Luls on our cross post. GET OUT OF MY HEAD!

Comment: By "final vote" it means "your votes for the final phase", so people don't see it and think "I already voted in the primaries"

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Perhaps it's just misleading text encouraging people to vote and not intended to go away when all your votes are cast?

---

**EDIT:** Cross posted with Ben, but the similarities are so striking that I'm leaving it up for the lulz. =)

Comment: I'm obviously spoiled with all the real-time stuff the stackexchange sites do that I expected too much on this occasion and jumped to a conclusion

Comment: I'm probably going to regret asking but what are "lulz"? It's clearly not English.

Comment: @John Lulz are what make the luliverse go 'round! http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=lulz

Comment: That's sad. Very sad.

Answer (score 2):

This banner will disappear after 48 hours, it's just to publicize the election for all users.

Comment: If it will disappear after 48 hours. How can I show it again?

Comment: @khaled you cannot, but there is an election topic on the relevant meta, and the url is simple to remember.. just add `/election` to the domain eg `serverfault.com/election`